# Java Spring: Error creating bean

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a spring project added to Eclipse. When I run project on server from eclipse, I get these errors:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myprojectwebsite-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.test.myproject.data.User"/> in the configuration:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.test.myproject.data.User"/> in the configuration:
```

myprojectwebsite-servlet.xml has:

```
...
<property name="configLocation">
   <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
...
```

and hibernate.cfg.xml has the code where error is being raised:

```
<mapping class="com.test.myproject.data.User"/>
```

Any idea what may be going wrong ?

Comment: Is the `User` class accessible at runtime?

Comment: Any way to check that? (The error which I pasted is from eclipse console)

Comment: In the directory where eclipse puts the compiler output, does that class exist?

Comment: click `ctrl+shift+t` and type `User` see what it shows?

Comment: Is your code on GitHub or something?

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace and the source code for `com.test.myproject.data.User`?

Comment: @Rembo: It shows the same mapping class mentioned in "hibernate.cfg.xml ",

geoand: Code is on private Github repo so I would not be able share that..